# R Add values to existing column in data frame by merging with other data frame

Tags: r, merge, left-join, tidyverse

Suppose I have the following data:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                   x  = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   y  = rep(NA, 4))

dat2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   y  = c(9, 8, 7))


dat3 <- data.frame(id = c("d"),
                   y  = c(6))
```

Now, I want to merge/join the data from `dat2` and `dat3` to dat1 one after the other in a way that the dat1$y values are **replaced** by the dat2.y or dat3.y values instead of adding these as new columns.

The problem is that `merge` or `left_join` would not add the values to the existing y column, but add a y.y column and rename the one from dat1 to y.x.

I also thought I could use the `rows_update` function from the tidyverse, but the problem is that in my real life case I'm not only matching by one column (here: id), but by several id columns together, but rows_update only allows the `by` variable to be one vector.

NOTE: in my real-life use case I have

- ~50 data frames to merge
- the uniqueness of my rows can only be determined through multiple id columns
- the id columns have different names in my dat1 and all other dat2 to dat50 data frames.

The expected output after merging dat2 and dat3 to dat1 would be:

```
id    x    y
"a"   1    9
"b"   2    8
"c"   3    7
"d"   4    6
```

Comment: OK, my mistake might have been that I tried to name them similarly to the left_join syntax (because also the id columns have different names in my real.life data frames). I'll update my post accordingly.

Comment: At any given position would you have only one `y` value from all the dataframes? Or there could be multiple `y` values and you would like to select the first one in the final `y` column?

Comment: Not sure if I'm following, but there is only one y value, yes.

Comment: OK, not sure where that comment has gone, but the easiest solution was to give all my data frames the same names for the id columns (i.e. changing the third condition in my post) and use the rows_update function from tidyverse. Works like a charme.

Answer (score 2):

Try with indexing using `%in%` to test the id variables:

```
#Data
dat1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                   x  = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   y  = rep(NA, 4))

dat2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   y  = c(9, 8, 7))


dat3 <- data.frame(id = c("d"),
                   y  = c(6))
#Code
dat1$y[dat1$id %in% dat2$id] <- dat2$y[dat2$id %in% dat1$id]
dat1$y[dat1$id %in% dat3$id] <- dat3$y[dat3$id %in% dat1$id]
```

Output:

```
  id x y
1  a 1 9
2  b 2 8
3  c 3 7
4  d 4 6
```

You can use a loop with a list to store the objects from `dat2` to `datn` and then make the assignation of values:

```
#Data
dat1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                   x  = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   y  = rep(NA, 4))

dat2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   y  = c(9, 8, 7))


dat3 <- data.frame(id = c("d"),
                   y  = c(6))
#Store Objects in a list
List <- list(dat2,dat3)
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(List))
{
  #Data
  df <- List[[i]]
  #Assign
  dat1$y[dat1$id %in% df$id] <- df$y[df$id %in% dat1$id]
}
```

Output:

```
dat1
  id x y
1  a 1 9
2  b 2 8
3  c 3 7
4  d 4 6
```

Comment: OK, I should have been a bit more precise. In reality I have like 50 or so data frames to merge, so that manual approach wouldn't be feasible.

Comment: @deschen Let me add a loop approach

Comment: @deschen I have added a loop approach, I hope that can be helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. However, as mentioned in a comment of my initial post, I decided for loosening the third condition in my post (i.e. I created the id names in a way that they are identical across all my data frames), so that now I can easily use the rows_update function from tidyverse. This essentially solves my problem with one line of code. Appreciate your help, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can get dataframes in a list and `left_join` them using `reduce`. If every row has only one `y` value we can use `rowSums`/`rowMeans` ignoring `NA` value.

```
library(dplyr)

mget(paste0('dat', 1:3)) %>%
  purrr::reduce(left_join, by = 'id') %>%
  mutate(y = rowSums(select(., starts_with('y')), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(id, x, y)

#  id x y
#1  a 1 9
#2  b 2 8
#3  c 3 7
#4  d 4 6
```

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. However, as mentioned in a comment of my initial post, I decided for loosening the third condition in my post (i.e. I created the id names in a way that they are identical across all my data frames), so that now I can easily use the `rows_update` function from tidyverse. This essentially solves my problem with one line of code. But I appreciate the creativity you put into your solution.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer - but maybe not too generalizable - would be:

```
dat1$y = c(dat2$y, dat3$y)
```

With a loop, to do this to several data frames:

```
newy = numeric()
for(i in 2:ndf){ # Where "ndf" is the number of data frames you have
    newy = c(newy, eval(parse(text=paste("dat",i,"$y",sep=""))))}
```

OBS: evaluating objects by strings, with the `eval(parse(text=...))` normaly isn't the best way to do it in R. It is probably best if the data frames were created together in a list (as listing them now would be very manual, atleast with my knowledge), and the loop would be:

```
newy = numeric()
for(i in 2:ndf){
    newy = c(newy, df.list[[i]]$y)}
```